# Efficiently create new fields across a MongoDB collection using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection with documents that have a field, call it `field1` and I would like to call a (complicated) python function `fxn` on each `field1` entry and store this in a new `field2`. My collection is quite large and `fxn` takes a few seconds to run so I would like to parallelize this across a few jobs. This is my approach so far:

```
for i, entry in enumerate(collection.find().sort('_id')):
    if i % nJobs != jobID: continue
    field1 = entry['field1']
    field2 = fxn(field1)
    collection.update({'_id': entry['_id']}, {'$set': {'field2':field2})
```

Where `nJobs` is the total number of jobs and `jobID` is the index of the current job (e.g. say I run this script in parallel 5 times, then `nJobs=5` and `jobID` ranges from 0 to 4)

Is there a faster or more reliable way to implement this? I would prefer to keep everything in python, since `fxn` needs to be kept in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would essentially need to use the **[Bulk API](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html)** where within the for-loop you take advantage of using a write commands Bulk API that allow for the execution of bulk update operations which are simply abstractions on top of the server to make it easy to build bulk operations. These bulk operations come mainly in two flavours:

- **Ordered bulk operations**. These operations execute all the operation in order and error out on the first write error.
- **Unordered bulk operations**. These operations execute all the operations in parallel and aggregates up all the errors. Unordered bulk operations do not guarantee order of execution.

This is quite efficient as you are not sending "every" request to the server, but just once in every 1000 requests and the api actually sorts this out for you under the hood. Note, for older servers than 2.6 the API will downconvert the operations. However it's not possible to downconvert 100% so there might be some edge cases where it cannot correctly report the right numbers.

Implementing this on a non-sharded cluster would require using the **[`snapshot`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-isolate-cursors)** parameter so that you can isolate your find cursor from seeing the same doc again after it's updated:

```
bulk = db.collection.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
counter = 0;

for entry in collection.find(snapshot = True):
    # process in bulk
    # calc field2 value first
    field2 = fxn(entry.field1)
    bulk.find({ '_id': entry._id }).update({ '$set': { 'field2': field2 } })
    counter++

    if ( counter % 1000 == 0 ):
        bulk.execute()
        bulk = db.collection.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

if (counter % 1000 != 0):
    bulk.execute()
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! As far as determining the entries to process from `jobID` and `nJobs`, do you see anything wrong with what I am doing now? I could also imagine using `skip` and `limit` to choose the right entries from the cursor.

Comment: It all depends on your application logic, the Bulk API under the hood executes the write operations in batches thereby reducing the number of network round trips, increasing write throughput, so you may not need the filter but worth trying out a microbenchmark to see the differences.

Comment: Oh, I more so need the filter because of the `fxn` run time and not necessarily the overhead from querying/updating

Comment: Well, in that case by all means include it :)